# disable checksum rails active storage paperclip migration aws s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, md5, checksum, rails-activestorage

Is there a way to disable checksum with active storage? I am migrating from paperclip to active storage, using amazon s3 storage. There is no way to get the get the md5 checksum encryption code without communicating with the bucket, which is too time consuming to migrate millions of attachments in our production database. The checksum column has a null: false constraint, and removing this raises errors in the migration and in uploading the file that seem to be unavoidable. I feel I must be missing something here, is there any way to avoid using the checksum column?

Comment: I too would like to know this and will post if I discover a way.

Comment: The way i worked around this was by removing the null: false constraint on the checksum value in the migration file. Then just placed a nil value for checksum in my rake task migrating assets from paperclip to active storage.

Comment: @BenSkiff what does your rake task look like? The checksum is used to validate the data for downloads and uploads. has it affected your production data?

Comment: @BenSkiff I am facing the same issue and thinking about ditching the checksum for migrating files. Did you find any problems because of having nil checksums, after the migration ended?

Comment: @Tashows (and Blair) Have not had issues with disabled checksum in production. The app however is mostly only used in house and does not have a particularly large user base, but still no issues.

Answer (score -1):

For some types of S3 objects as described below, the Etag is the MD5 checksum of the file.

*"Objects created by the PUT Object, POST Object, or Copy operation, or    through the AWS Management Console, and are encrypted by SSE-S3 or    plaintext, have ETags that are an MD5 digest of their object data.
Objects created by the PUT Object, POST Object, or Copy operation, or    through the AWS Management Console, and are encrypted by SSE-C or    SSE-KMS, have ETags that are not an MD5 digest of their object data.
If an object is created by either the Multipart Upload or Part Copy    operation, the ETag is not an MD5 digest, regardless of the method of    encryption"*

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

If your use case matches the above, you will able to use that instead of downloading and digesting the whole file.

My code to do this is like:

```
key = "#{id}/#{filename}"
resp = @s3client.head_object({bucket: @bucket, key: key})
checksum_base64 = [[resp.etag].pack("H*")].pack("m0")
```

For better performance, you can use the `client#list_objects` API to grab `ObjectSummary` records in bulk for your entire bucket, or a subset and use those to look up the Etag/checksum.

I haven't totally tested this end-to-end with ActiveSupport. *(It generally isn't a good drop-in replacement for Paperclip right now. In particular, lack of support for multiple buckets is a bit of a show-stopper for us at the moment)*.

Comment: sounds like a better way to perform the migration than any I have seen. But i ended up just leaving the checksum nil.

Comment: Etag is not always the MD5 checksum! See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html for details.

Comment: It used to be only multipart uploads where that was the case. Now that has extended to other things, but there are common cases, like our system, where you can still rely on that. I'll amend.

Comment: Sure but you can't rely on the ETag, when uploaded as multipart, in Active Storage because it will fail on integrity check later (at least with 5.2.3)